# Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] Device not working

Tags: iwlwifi, 19.10

The Additional drivers dialog is showing this:
[image: The additional drivers dialog is showing this:]

Does this mean that my system won't connect to Wireless AC networks? Is there a way around this?

`lspci -v` gives the following output"

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at a121c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

I'm using a Dell Inspiron 14 (5482)

Comment: What computer are you using? What are it's specs? Please edit your answer to include this info

Comment: Go to update tab > enable backports > apply and reload the package lists. Then reopen again  Additional drivers tab, see it get enabled ?

Comment: Backports was already enabled.

Comment: @user.dz: Same here: eoan backports is enabled, the dialog is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I still can't comment so it's hard to ask clarifying questions. It looks like there were known issues with this WiFi card on Linux firmware version 20190628. AFAICT it was fixed upstream: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203315

I would suggest one of two possible lines of action. The first, is simply try the recently released 20.04 live CD and see if your WiFi works in that live environment. 20.04 will have a newer kernel than 19.10 did and so should include this firmware fix.

If for some reason that's not an option or does not work you can always install the backports iwlwifi kernel module via the command line:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

I'll be honest, I'm not sure the iwlwifi kernel module will actually help if it's a Linux firmware bug. So my recommendation would be to try and prefer the 20.04 live CD solution.

Comment: Sounds good. The funny thing is that WiFi works just fine, in spite of the dialog displayed above being shown on my system. Would that be the expected behavior? Also, I will wait another couple of weeks with the upgrade to 20.04, but I will comment again if it really solves the issue.

Comment: I've upgraded to 20.04. The additional drivers dialog still shows the same thing. My wifi works, but have never tried to connect to a wi-fi access point that was using the AC protocol only.

Comment: @ToDo can you post the output of `lspci -v`? Specifically I only need anything that's relating to wifi.

My suspicion is that everything is fine and the additional hardware dialog is probably just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After a while I just power cycled my laptop (held power button for 10s) instead of restarting and somehow that fixed it.

Comment: This helped me as well, I followed the "power drain" protocol from https://support.lenovo.com/sv/en/troubleshoot/lpt000352