# Intel Cannon Point-LP network UNCLAIMED (Ubuntu 20.10)

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

From one minute to the next, my wifi stopped working.
I'm kind of a noob, every help is appreciated!

Laptop

Asus Zenbook UX433F

Distro (Linux only)

```
Ubuntu 20.10 groovy

uname -r
5.8.0-63-generic
```

More info

sudo lshw -C network

```
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b121c000-b121ffff
```

sudo dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    3.183994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.185548] iwlwifi: No config found for PCI dev 9df0/0000, rev=0x318, rfid=0x0
[    3.246743] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Coffee Lake HOST and DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Thermal Controller (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Shared SRAM (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO UART Controller #2 (rev 30)
00:1e.2 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP Serial IO SPI Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Black 2018/PC SN520 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
```

rfkill list

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Past EOL and out of support maybe upgrade?

Comment: You may want to upgrade to 21.04. Also, have you seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1186106/1222991) and it’s answers? 

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 is the 2020-October (ie. a *year.month* format is used for releases) release of Ubuntu; it was not a LTS (*long-term-support*) release meaning it had 9 months of support, upgrading to the next release (21.04 or 2021-April release). Oct+9 months =2021.July for EOL.  The kernel 5.8 is no longer *patched* for security-flaws (it's EOL) so be careful online (ie. *release-upgrade* asap) and consider a LTS release if you don't want to *release-upgrade* every 6-9 months as required for non-LTS releases.

Comment: Thank you!
I was not aware of 20.10. reached it's end of life.
I've updated to 20.10 and kernel 5.11.

I've tried the backwards iwlwifi
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms

and a "power drain".

Still, the problem persists. Any ideas on where to start?