No wifi and bluetooth on 22.04 (and on 20.04)
I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 for 3 years on a system76 darter pro from 2019. (IIRC its some kind of Clevo machine), previously I've run various linux distros on the machine, and on other ones too.
Well, yesterday in the middle of a lecture I was giving the wireless took a crap and dies (typical behavior with the garbage university wireless) and I panic rebooted a couple times. Well, somehow that effed the wireless settings and/or driver. I tried a large number of stackoverflow/itsfoss/askubuntu fixes, including upgrading to ubuntu 22.04. Nothing works, in fact, now the bluetooth wont turn on either. A series of hard boots has at least put the wireless option back in the top right menu, but when I turn it on it detects no wireless networks. Here is the output from
lshw -C network

*-network DISABLED        
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 30
       serial: 3c:f0:11:fe:00:b5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-116-generic firmware=46.fae53a8b.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0- latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:148 memory:6023104000-6023107fff

and
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0034]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

please help!

Can you reboot with a live session and try to connect to see if the problem is related to software or hardware?

@TalaatEtman ok from live session, sill getting this from lshw, the network is disabled. So you think its hardware preventing the activation of the network?
'''
*-network DISABLED
description: Wireless interface
product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 14.3
bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
'''

if there is a key in your keyboard to enable/disable wifi check it may be you disabled it. install the driver in the live session and see if it solved or not.

@TalaatEtman There is no such keyboard wifi button, and on live session (24.04) booted from USB there is no option to install additional drivers in the GUI "additional drivers" tool
Also at the moment, the live session shows that the wifi is on, but it doesn't detect any networks. Sometimes the laptop doesn't think the wifi is on at all and wont turn it on from the GUI, and command line things like restarting NetworkManager also dont work.

see this question and answers https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186106/cannon-point-lp-cnvi-wireless-ac-device-not-working

@TalaatEtman I tried both of those before I posted the question...

do you have windows to try it. if it doesn't work in windows, send your pc to repair.

@TalaatEtman I installed PopOS22.04 and that worked until I tried again to connect to the stupid university wireless, then the whole problem started again. I hard booted/power drained and connected to my home wireless, everything fine.
ubuntu 24.04 didnt work though. Do you know why PopOS would not have this issue?

I think this problem is related to low-bettery sittings or power sittings, and after testing on another os it not related to the hardware.
